# Kafka Connect RetriableCommitFailedException - What actions to take

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Every so often our Kafka connect log is getting this error. (Replaced my topic names for , , etc)

```
[2020-02-20 06:22:22,169] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=s3connector-quoteandbind-0} Commit of offsets threw an unexpected exception for sequence number 288: 
{<topicname1>-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=0, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}, <topicname2>-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=6096, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}, <topicname3>-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=8023, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}, <topicname4>-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=6880, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}, 
<topicname5>-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=15745, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}, <topicname6>-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=6300, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}, <topicname7>-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=0, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}, <topicname8>-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=0, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}, <topicname9>-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=3875, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}, <topicname10>-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=5212, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}, <topicname11>-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=0, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}, <topicname12>-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=25761, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}, 
<topicname13>-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=768, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}, <topicname14>-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=30495, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}, <topicname15>-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=48136, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}, <topicname16>-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=31, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}, 
<topicname17>-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=6422, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}, <topicname18>-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=0, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}, <topicname19>-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=8471, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}, <topicname20>-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=22256, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}, <topicname21>-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=5520, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}, <topicname22>-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=29302, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}, <topicname23>-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=6880, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}, <topicname24>-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=21220, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}, 
<topicname25>-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=20881, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}, <topicname26>-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=144, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}, <topicname27>-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=3877, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}, <topicname28>-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=5324, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}, <topicname29>-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=5047, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}, <topicname30>-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=21637, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}, 
<topicname31>-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=2860, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask)
************
************
timestamp: 2020-02-20T06:22:22.169Z
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RetriableCommitFailedException: Offset commit failed with a retriable exception. You should retry committing the latest consumed offsets.
************
```

Does anyone know the behaviour of Kafka-Connect after this? Is there an automatic retry or is there a manual step that needs to be done by a developer?

Does this mean we have lost some data?

Thanks.

Comment: Well the developer has to restart the connector manually.

Comment: You suggest restarting the connector after getting this error?

Comment: Yes, as none of the messages is committed, if you restart the connector, you will be able to read the messages again.

Comment: Is the error you posted occurred in your logs ?

Comment: Yea seeing this error in my logs, do I need to restart my connect service on my ec2 instance then?

Comment: Yes, try to restart the connector.

Comment: Connect should retry any retriable exceptions

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007 thats what I needed to know. Put it as an answer if you want and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A retryable exception is a transient exception that if retried may succeed.

https://kafka.apache.org/20/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/errors/RetriableException.html

I am unsure if Connect will restart these processes on its own, but the S3 connector in particular has exactly once semantics, so therefore it should continue to retry the same operation

The other way to "retry" would be restart the connector process or the connector tasks via the REST API